# Playback error on using ClearKey DRM Schema in Exoplayer 2 android

Tags: android, exoplayer, drm, mpeg-dash, exoplayer2.x

I am trying to play the **.MPD** file, which is using

**DRMSchema** : clearKey

For playing it i am creating a *DefaultDrmSessionManager* in the following way

```
 String keyString = "{\"keys\":[{\"kty\":\"oct\",\"k\":\"y1QQhMmXMa70__dFAMEurQ\n" +
                "    \",\"kid\":\"bXbyXLF_Xha46u9rv1gtjg\n" +
                "    \"},{\"kty\":\"oct\",\"k\":\"pGMaFTpEPfnu0FkwQ9t1GQ\n" +
                "    \",\"kid\":\"88XgNh5mVLKPgEnHeLI5Rg\n" +
                "    \"}],'type':\"temporary\"}";

LogMgr.i("DRMCallback JSON : " + keyString);

drmCallback = new LocalMediaDrmCallback(keyString.getBytes());

mediaDrm = FrameworkMediaDrm.newInstance(uuid);

DefaultDrmSessionManager<FrameworkMediaCrypto> drmSessionManager = new DefaultDrmSessionManager<>(uuid, mediaDrm, drmCallback, null, multiSession);
```

After that, when i am trying to use this *DefaultDrmSessionManager* for playing the video, i am getting *ExoPlayerImplInternal: Playback error*,  i am attaching the Log for reference.

```
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: **Playback error**.
com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.feedInputBuffer(MediaCodecRenderer.java:780)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.render(MediaCodecRenderer.java:583)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:518)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:301)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
 Caused by: android.media.MediaCodec$CryptoException: **Crypto key not available**
    at android.media.MediaCodec.native_queueSecureInputBuffer(Native Method)
    at android.media.MediaCodec.queueSecureInputBuffer(MediaCodec.java:2547)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.feedInputBuffer(MediaCodecRenderer.java:771)
```

Please guide me, what i am doing wrong

Comment: Hey, I need help regarding a similar issue in my project. Tried sending you a request over on linkedIn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working fine after removing \n from the keyString.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the length of the key string, the most likely problem is that the key has not been base64URL encoded in the call to LocalMediaDrmCallback.

An AES 128-bit key will be:

- 32 characters as a hex key
- 24 characters when base64 encoded

Assuming that a4631a153a443df9eed0593043db7519 is the key in hex format then you need to convert it (and the keyID also) to base64 and then pass them this way to LocalMediaDrmCallback.

Using one of the common online convertors you can see this would give:

- hex key: a4631a153a443df9eed0593043db7519
- base64 encoded pGMaFTpEPfnu0FkwQ9t1GQ==

You can see an example of doing this programmatically also in this GitHub issue answer: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/3856#issuecomment-366197586

Comment: Thanks @Mick, your answer really helps me to work on right Base64Url  key implementation. But, after implementing it also i am getting the same error.
In my logcat i am getting **Crypto key not available**, can you please help me with this.