# How to download ClearKey Encrypted Video in ExoPlayer 2

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x, android-drm

I am having a **.MPD** file which is encrypted via **ClearKey DRM scheme**. I am able to play this file in Exoplayer2 with internet connectivity. Exoplayer2 is using ***LocalMediaDrmCallback*** for licensing the **.MPD** file

Now, i am trying to **download this video offline**, after that playing that offline video in Exoplayer2(without internet connectivity).

Till now i have tried to use ***DashDownloadHelper*** to download the video from **.MPD** file. Please guide me how to provide licensing information while downloading the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply download the content like normal .MPD file and **do the licensing in two ways** i.e.

- online while playing the video using HttpMediaDrmCallback

> ```
>  HttpDataSource.Factory licenseDataSourceFactory = CinemaApplication.getAppInstance().buildHttpDataSourceFactory();
>             HttpMediaDrmCallback httpMediaDrmCallback =
>                     new HttpMediaDrmCallback(licenseUrl, licenseDataSourceFactory);
>             if (keyRequestPropertiesArray != null) {
>                 for (int i = 0; i < keyRequestPropertiesArray.length - 1; i += 2) {
>                     httpMediaDrmCallback.setKeyRequestProperty(keyRequestPropertiesArray[i],
>                             keyRequestPropertiesArray[i + 1]);
>                 }
>             }
> ```

- By using LocalMediaDrmCallback

  > drmCallback = new
  >   LocalMediaDrmCallback(PlayerActivity.KEY_JSON.getBytes());

Using the above drmCallback, make te instance of DefaultDrmSessionManager

```
releaseMediaDrm();
mediaDrm = FrameworkMediaDrm.newInstance(uuid);
DefaultDrmSessionManager<FrameworkMediaCrypto> drmSessionManager = new DefaultDrmSessionManager<>(uuid, mediaDrm, drmCallback, null, false);
```

[For more reference for offline ClearKey License](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53426119/3959610)